# What should we do when an answer is negatively voted without comments?

Tags: discussion

I have been experiencing this now quite often . Some of my answers are negatively voted without any further reasons .While I appreciate people down voting the answers if there is no proper info or incorrect info,I would encourage downvoters to atleast leave a comment with reasoning on why a particular answer should be deleted or deserve a negative vote .Is this something moderators can help with and whats the right attitude here ?

A great example for downvote is [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114150/salesforce-lightning-ready-certification/114225) answer .The answer produced is from the notes I took on one of the calls I had with Salesforce Lightning Ready Certification jury team and I cant really think of a reason why someone is not happy with the answer .

Comment: I upvoted to compensate. :D

Comment: @SebastianKessel lol :D ..Thanks :) .That was really some dude voting negatively ..

Comment: Its great answer, upvote from me as well on that Mohit. don't let downvoters demotivate your awesomeness .

Comment: @JitendraZaa Thank you for support .I love keep contributing and if anyone wants to downvote they are free to do so provided they have valid reasons .

Comment: This is not something moderators can with, at least no more than any other member. Unless you notice patterns and serial down voting.

Comment: What to do when someone downvotes a question without a comment? Like this [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114917/how-to-send-welcome-email-via-api)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have a strong upvote culture here relative to other exchanges I have participated in. That's the correct approach: you build a culture. It takes a large series of small actions to make it work. Asking why there is a downvote is a *great* way to reinforce that culture. As a community, we are not happy about unexplained downvotes. They do not improve the community. That is partly why it is so rare to see any of them unless a post is so bad it deserves many downvotes, for which one explanation can often suffice as a consensus.

So, voting down *when appropriate* is actually an important reinforcement of our culture here, because you can demonstrate what a good explanation looks like. Our strong moderator community also helps. If a post is worth voting down, then it surely is worth flagging to close or delete. It all adds up to make the behavior you describe mostly anomalous, thankfully.

If you have noticed a change in this trend, I feel it must still be fought with a series of small steps. Your reaction was perfect and fully sufficient. Glad I voted you back to zero, looks like it was well worth the upvote!

Comment: Cant agree more . I see lot of upvotes and also it was accepted as an answer which definitely speaks about the awesome culture and excellent attitude folks on this forums has . Thanks again to everyone for doing what was right here and confirming the answer had some value . Just want to make a request if you downvote be sure to explain the reason why a negative vote was made .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yep, I love that part of our culture, but it's only so strong because we are vigilant about reinforcing it every time.

Comment: Completely agree :)

Comment: I'm happy to see consistency here with the recent Meta discussion on etiquette/solicitation: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/what-sfse-etiquette-should-be-followed?cb=1

Comment: Can you please advise what to do when someone downvotes a [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114917/how-to-send-welcome-email-via-api) without any comments?

Comment: @Bennie Not sure why that was dowvoted .I just upvoted it and its very valid question

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thank you Mohith